# Can't Open Password-Protected Word Document With LibreOffice Writer

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-writer, password-protection

I have a `.doc` document that I can't seem to open properly with LibreOffice. The only content is some text noting that I need to open it with MS Office:

```
This document has been protected.
Please use Microsoft Office to open the document. You will be asked to enter
your email address and Intralinks password.
```

I'm not sure how it was password-protected, and maybe Intralinks has its own proprietary methods. Or maybe it is too old for LibreOffice to un-protect it, given that it is `.doc`, not `.docx`. I have looked in Tools and File>Properties, but I only see ways to protect it, not un-protect it.

Are there ways to password-protect `.doc(x)` files so that only MS Word can open them, not LibreOffice/OpenOffice, at least with current versions? What are some other things I can try to un-protect the document so I can read it?

Comment: Are you or some one you know able to open the document in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather use LibreOffice.

Comment: I was thinking that you might open it, remove any protections, save it and then go back to LibreOffice.

Comment: I didn't create the document.

Comment: So, follow John's suggestion even if you didn't create the document. Open in MS Office, remove protections, save.

Comment: It seems that [LibreOffice can open only some sepcific password-encrypted Microsoft Word files](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/About_Converting_Microsoft_Office_Documents#Opening_Microsoft_Office_Documents_That_Are_Protected_With_a_Password).